# SQL: Get percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
 select
COUNT(pc.property_id) AS [Total Count of Closed],
SUM(pc.sale_price) AS [Total Sum of Sales Price],
SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds) AS [Total Sum of Net Proceeds],
SUM(pc.sale_price) * 100 / SUM(pc.sale_price) AS [Percentage of Total Sales Price],
SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds) * 100 / SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds) AS [Percentage of Total Net Proceeds],

AVG(DATEDIFF(day,pd.list_dt,pc.close_dt)) AS [Average Days from List Date to Close Date]
 from resnet_mysql.dbo.property_closings pc
join resnet_mysql.dbo.property_details pd
    on pc.property_id = pd.property_id

 where pc.res_id = 201
```

I'm trying to get the Percentage of Total Sales price, but I keep getting 100%. Please help.

[Here is a screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RAgX8FL-Z0Yks5N1c1d3lFN00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you are dividing by the same thing..you'll obviously get 100%.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post images

Comment: Put the link that we edit for you.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want window functions.  I would also explicitly use non-integers -- just in case (SQL Server does integer division on integers so 1/2 = 0 not 0.5):

```
SUM(pc.sale_price) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(pc.sale_price) OVER () AS [Percentage of Total Sales Price],
SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds)) OVER () AS [Percentage of Total Net Proceeds],
```

Note the `SUM(SUM())` and `OVER ()`.  These take the sum of the value over all the rows.

Comment: It gives me 100% still.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(SUM(pc.sale_price)) OVER ()` sums the aggregated sums using a Windowed Aggregate:

```
SUM(pc.sale_price) * 100 / SUM(SUM(pc.sale_price)) OVER () AS [Percentage of Total Sales Price],
SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds) * 100 / SUM(SUM(pc.advanced_seller_proceeds)) OVER () AS [Percentage of Total Net Proceeds],
```

Comment: I still get 100% though, wierd. should just be 1 row with the percentage of the total

Comment: @csowner17: Oops, of course, there's only a single row in your result set, you probably need a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I want it to only be 1 single row though.

Comment: @csowner17: Ok, so what percentage do you want? Those `where pc.res_id = 201` compared to all rows?

Comment: you need to divide by it count of total sale

Comment: percentage of the sum of total sales price.

Comment: @csowner17: Please edit your question and show your expected result and explain how its calculated.